# Problem to obtain the residuals with the R package stochvol

Tags: r, time-series, finance

I am trying to obtain the residuals after to fit a model with the *stochvol* package's function *svsample()*.

```
library(stochvol)
#simulated data
y <- svsim(len=10000, mu = -8, phi = 0.98, sigma = 0.15)
plot(y, type="l")
#fitting the model
modStoch <- svsample(y, priormu = c(-10, 1), priorphi = c(20, 1.1), priorsigma = 0.1)
summary(modStoch)
plot(modStoch)

#residuals of the model
res <- resid(modStoch)
#res <- residuals(modStoch) this line doesn't work neither
```

This is the error:

**Error in t(object$latent)/2 : argumento no-numérico para operador binario**

I have tested several versions of R and the error remains.

¡Thank you!

Comment: Apparently you have an object with a varaable called "latent". This should be numeric, but it isnt. Please provide some data so we can help you. Search SO for the question on how to provide a great reproducible example.

Comment: With the data simulated to create the variable **y** should be enough to run the code